# Rewrite exposed filter input from url

Tags: taxonomy-terms, search, views

I have created a view to list nodes path **articlesearch**.

Now i want to filter the content with a search string based on title, body and taxonomy term with OR condition

One issue i am facing is i want to use only one search parameter that will be used to match to find the string in title body and tags.

```
e.g. http://example.com/articlesearch?s=as
```

Other issue is that when i expose parameter to search content from url, it will work fine for title and body. But when i use the same string to search between tags, views shows error and no content appears. Because views matches the exact taxonomy term name/term id.

**Basically my requirement is:-**

1. One search parameter that will be used to find the content from title, body and tags
2. Or i want to use taxonomy term name in LIKE condition so it will not show any error if exact term id/term name is not passed to it.
3. Or i can override the url parameter before  passed to view

I don't know how to achieve this requirement.

Help would be greatly appreciated.